# Get last character of string using `format`

Tags: python, string-formatting

I have to build a path from a given id using this template :

```
<last digit of id>/<second last digit of id>/<full id>
```

For instance, if my id is `3412`, the expected result would be :

```
2/1/3412
```

The id is supposed to have at least 2 digits.
The first thing I tried was:

```
>>> "{my_id[3]}/{my_id[2]}/{my_id}".format(my_id=str(3412))
'2/1/3412'
```

But this would work only if the id is 4 digits long.

So what I was expecting to do then was:

```
>>> "{my_id[-1]}/{my_id[-2]}/{my_id}".format(my_id=str(3412))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

My question here is why can't I use negative indices in my string specifier? And why is Python telling me I'm not using integer indices? I didn't find anything in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) about it.

I know there are many other ways to do this, but I'm just curious about why this one does not work.

I'm using python 2.7, but the behaviour seems to be the same under python 3.4.

Comment: https://bugs.python.org/issue7951

Comment: https://bugs.python.org/issue8985

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [vaultah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2301450/vaultah) and [Bhargav Rao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4099593/bhargav-rao) reported in the comments, this is a known issue of python. I'll just have to find an alternative solution!

```
>>> my_id = str(3412)
>>> "{}/{}/{}".format(my_id[-1], my_id[-2], my_id)
'2/1/3412'
```